# Batch check if IP is within specific range

Tags: networking, ip, batch-file, ip-address, range

I'm trying to make a batch script to get local IP-address of active NIC (could be wireless or local).
To get IP adress I have used following line:

```
FOR /F "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 %computername% -n 1 ^| findstr "["') do (set thisip=%%a)
```

I then have the IP address. The range is depending of the second group (eg. 64 in 172.64.10.10).
I would like to launch a script if the local IP address is within 64 - 127 in the second group.

How can I do that?

I already tried  to export the value in the second group but then I must export two or three characters:

```
SET IP=%thisip:~3,2%
```

Then I have managed to loop through the numbers but I am thinking wrong I don´t want to run the script more then once and my loop runs several times depending of what the IP Adress is:

```
:MyLoop
IF "%IP%" LSS "64" GOTO EndLoop
IF "%IP%" GTR "99" GOTO EndLoop
ECHO %IP%
SET /A IP+=1
GOTO MyLoop
:EndLoop
```

Comment: I have tried to do as follow to check the different criterias but it does allways print the "You´re NOT within the range!", why is that?
`code`
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 %computername% -n 1 ^| findstr "["') do (set thisip=%%a)
SET IP=%thisip:~2,3%
SET _result=%IP:.=%
IF %_result% LSS "127" GOTO :ResultTrue
IF %_result% GEQ "127" GOTO :ResultFalse
:ResultTrue
IF %_result% GEQ "64" GOTO :TrueResult
:TrueResult
    ECHO %thisip%
    ECHO %IP%
    ECHO %_result%
    ECHO "You´re within the range!"
:ResultFalse
    ECHO "You´re NOT within the range!"
PAUSE

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need, all in one batch file.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "thisIP="
set /a SecondGroup=0
set /a RangeStart=64
set /a RangeEnd=127

for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%A in ('ping -4 %computername% -n 1 ^| findstr "["') do (set thisIP=%%A)

for /f "delims=. tokens=1,2,3,4" %%A in ("!thisIP!") do set /a SecondGroup=%%B

if !SecondGroup! GEQ !RangeStart! (
  if !SecondGroup! LEQ !RangeEnd! (
    echo Let's execute you code here.
  ) else (
    echo IP is too high.
  )
) else (
  echo IP is too low.
)

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
endlocal
```

Remember to remove `ECHO` commands if you don't need them. I inserted them for clarification purpose only.